# .Net core External login not working on chrome

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc, facebook-oauth

I have a very strange issue on Facebook login in .Net core.
Everything was working fine until today, now the ExternalLoginCallback method is not getting called but it only happens on Chrome. I tried on Firefox and Safari and the login works perfectly but whenever I try on Chrome I am just being redirected to the login page.

I tried to clear the site data but it didnt help

Any idea about it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it only happens on Chrome. I tried on Firefox and Safari and the login works perfectly but whenever I try on Chrome I am just being redirected to the login page.

I assume that you have configured [Facebook authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-3.1) service correctly in your ASP.NET Core project, so it can work well on Firefox and Safari.

You mentioned that the issue only happens on Chrome, perhaps something wrong with your Chrome or Settings. Please check if you blocked all cookies or configured site(s) that can never use cookies in Chrome browser settings.

Besides, if possible, you can reset Chrome browser settings or reinstall Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is definitely a problem with my browser as I tried on another computer and it works fine with Chrome there. I will try to reinstall Chrome on the computer where it fails